# Web.config xmlns attribute while reading it in xslt.Problems

Tags: c#, xml, xslt, web.config-transform

A web.config file has a following line

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

I tried reading the web.config it in XSLT ([Get value from web.config into XSLT file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826017/get-value-from-web-config-into-xslt-file)) .I was unsuccessful, and i tried removing the xmlns attribute from the config file and i was able to read it in XSLT without much problem.

Whats the benefit/difference in having in xmlns attribute in web.config file and is it possible to read the config file into xslt with the xmlns attribute in web.config?

Comment: Please refer to the question for a similar implementation...http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23826017/get-value-from-web-config-into-xslt-file

Comment: Show us the code. How are you reading the file? Have you added this namespace to your xpath query, if any, to read the values?

Comment: @Oscar Please see the Link in the edited question for the code i tried to implement

Answer (score 1, accepted):

See this similar questions: How to read a node value with namespace, in xslt and c#.

[Problem with XSLT getting values from tags with namespace prefixes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3334727/problem-with-xslt-getting-values-from-tags-with-namespace-prefixes)

[How to get an specific node in xml with namespaces?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17258065/how-to-get-an-specific-node-in-xml-with-namespaces)